# Mandelbrot Set Running Immensely Slow

Tags: c++, performance, beginner

The program is running immensely slow even when moving around for only a small amount of distance. When zooming, I can't get any deeper of it and even if I can my computer starts lagging and I have to terminate it by force.

The program outputs the Mandelbrot set correctly but I can't really be sure if my computation is right and maybe that's what causing it very very slow. 
Can you please review my code in terms of efficiency and how should I make it fast?.

My computer specs are:

CPU: Intel i5-4590 3.30Ghz

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4600

RAM: 8GB

```
 #include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

    using namespace sf;

    int mandelSet(double dx, double dy, double c_Re, double c_Im, int maxIterator);
    Color  setPixelColor(int z, int maxIterator);

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int width = 700;
        unsigned int height = 700;

        double minRe = -1.2;
        double minIm = -2.0;
        double maxRe = 1.2;
        double maxIm = 2.0;
        float zoom = 1;

        double re = (maxRe - minRe) / (width);
        double im = (maxIm - minIm) / (height);

        const int maxIterator = 7000;

        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Mandelbrot set");

        Image image;
        image.create(width, height, sf::Color(0, 0, 0.0, 0));

        Texture texture;
        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        Sprite sprite(texture);
        sf::Event event; Keyboard keyboard;

        while (window.isOpen())
        {

            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            if (keyboard.isKeyPressed(keyboard.E))
            {
                zoom *= .9;
            }

            for (size_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                // transform cartesian coordinate Y to Imaginary complex number or scale Y
                double c_Im = ((y * im) + minIm) * zoom;

                for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // transform cartesian coordinate X to Real complex number or scale x
                    double c_Re = ((x * re) + minRe) * zoom + minRe;
                    double dy = 0, dx = 0;

                    int z = mandelSet(dx, dy, c_Re, c_Im, maxIterator);
                    Color color = setPixelColor(z, maxIterator);
                    image.setPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            texture.update(image);

            window.clear();
            window.draw(sprite);
            window.display();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Methods:

```
  int mandelSet(double dx, double dy, double c_Re, double c_Im, int maxIterator)
    {
        int z = 0;
        while (dx * dx + dy * dy < 4 && z < maxIterator)
        {
            double temp = ((dx * dx - dy * dy) + c_Re);
            dy = 2 * dx * dy + c_Im;
            dx = temp;
            z++;
        }
        return z;
    }

  Color setPixelColor(int z, int maxIterator)
    {
        Color color;
        if (z == maxIterator)
        {
            color = Color::Black;
        }
        else
        {
            color.r = z % 255 * z % 255;
            color.g = z % 255 * z % 255;
            color.b = z % 255;
        }
        return color;
    }
```

worst_mandelbrot_ever.jpg
[image]

Comment: Try changing your `maxIterator` to something like 500 or so, and see if it doesn't improve seem (quite) a bit.